# Any clue to create natural shadow like this?

Tags: architecture, unreal-4

I only use **skylight** with hdri map for overcast lighting. The corner isn't dark enough compare to other's work. Any clue to achieve this natural falloff soft shadow?

*What I want*

[image]

*What I get*

[image]

*My world settings*

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I've tried more bounces. It's just more bright overall instead of more contrast. The algorithm maybe not good enough. But some people achieve that decent result. I want to know how.

Comment: With an all-white room, light will keep bouncing quite a lot and fill in most of your corners. You need something to eat some of the light, like the darker walls in your example image.

Comment: @DMGregory Thanks, I'll try.

Answer (score 0):

It is all about the directional light intensity , try to lower the intensity of directional light and the build the lighting , you will get the output you want .

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/106705)